# Why does my cursor in css it's not working?

Tags: html, css

i started to program recently , and i'm trying to do an client are button and it's not working. Maybe some of you can help me

```css
.areacliente {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 13px;
  width: 130px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  text-align: right;
  transition: .3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn {
  border: 1.2px solid #8e44ad;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #9b59b6;
  list-style: none;
}

.btn li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="areacliente">
  <ul class="btn">
    <li><a href="#">Client Area<i id="lock"class="fas fa-user-lock"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How to work button explain?

Comment: What specifically isn't working as you expect it to?

Comment: it's simple , this button will redirect the person to and client area to register and log in

Comment: @Claudiu then change your `href`: `<a href="register_page.html">` ?

Comment: not sure I get the question here... are you asking why the a tag does not redirect or perform an action? or what?

Comment: @NickParsons that's what i did before and still not working , when i click nothing happens , the curson remain the default

Comment: @Claudiu did you put a valid directory in your `href`? any errors in the console when you pressed the button (with the `href` attribute set?)

Comment: @NickParsons No , nothing happens , i can't even click on my supposed button :/

Comment: @Claudiu in the code snippet you provided, when I enter `"https://www.google.com"` (a valid link/directory) as the `href` I am able to click on your button and it sends me to google. I can only think that it is an issue with the file your trying to redirect to... (from what I can see)

Comment: @NickParsons i've some code before , maybe the code before is doing something to my code ,

Comment: It might be. If an element is overlapping your button it could prevent it from being clicked. Or if you have some Javascript that could be interfering with it

Comment: @NickParsons How can i send the code to you ? maybe you can see something that i did wrong

Comment: If it is simple enough you can copy paste it into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or you can upload it to [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla) or you can create a github repo with it, or upload it to google docs so I can download it

Comment: @NickParsons https://jsfiddle.net/zyon12/thj0okp3/

Comment: @Claudiu please see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that your `nav` is floating on top of your 'Client Area' button so you can click on it. To fix this you need to change the `z-index` of this button:

```
.areacliente {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 13px;
    width: 130px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    text-align : right;
    transition: .3s;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1; /* Add this */
}
```

This will bring the button above the `nav` so you can now click on it.

See working example in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/08vaocjz/).

Comment: Thank you ! have a great day

Comment: @Claudiu no worries. glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.areacliente {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 13px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  text-align: right;
  transition: .3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn {
  border: 1.2px solid #8e44ad;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #9b59b6;
  list-style: none;
}

.btn li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="areacliente">
  <ul class="btn">
    <li><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Client Area<i id="lock"class="fas fa-user-lock"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I think left side space problem.so  width: 100px; only use remove other one  width: 130px

```
 .areacliente {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 13px;
  width: 130px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  text-align: right;
  transition: .3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: href inside add expect link page. solve your problem.

Comment: Still not working , my pointer appears , but 10px above my button

Comment: what you mean ?

Comment: Please check my new answer

Comment: Are you expect that answer?